# Topological sort while traversing?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph, graph-algorithm, topological-sort

Is it possible to topologically sort a directed acyclic graph while traversing it?

One of the extra conditions that holds true for my case is that there is always exactly one vertex that has no incoming edges in my DAG. (My case is a file dependency structure in compilation with only a single entry file.)

I'm wondering if it would be possible to build the topologically sorted list while traversing the graph instead of finding every vertex first and then sort afterwards.

Comment: What is the difference between "traversing all graph" and "finding every vertex" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could find topological sort of DAG graph by running a modified DFS which traverses the graph:

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting):

> An algorithm for topological sorting is based on depth-first search.
>   The algorithm loops through each node of the graph, in an arbitrary
>   order, initiating a depth-first search that terminates when it hits
>   any node that has already been visited since the beginning of the
>   topological sort or the node has no outgoing edges (i.e. a leaf node):

```
L ← Empty list that will contain the sorted nodes
while there are unmarked nodes do
    select an unmarked node n
    visit(n) 


 function visit(node n)
    if n has a permanent mark then return
    if n has a temporary mark then stop (not a DAG)
    mark n temporarily
    for each node m with an edge from n to m do
        visit(m)
    mark n permanently
    add n to head of L
```

You can find many implementations if you google it, one implementation you can find [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting/).

Comment: I guess this is the best way to do it!

Comment: Yes as far I know best algorithm for topological sort  is the modified dfs, O(n+m)...